# How to change the display language everywhere on a Windows 7 Enterprise edition?

Tags: windows-7, language, language-pack

I got a new notebook with Win7 Enterprise, Hungarian language. I like to use my OS fully in English, so I downloaded the English language pack and installed it. Now *98%* of the user interface is in English all right, but I still bump into the occasional Hungarian language labels. For example, on the login screen I'm prompted to enter my "Jelszó" instead of "Password".

Is there a way to check non-translated labels in Win7 installation?
Is there a way to make sure that Win7 will use English, and only English, and nothing else but English after installing a language pack?

Köszönöm errghh thank you.

(Additional info: this was a vanilla win7 OEM, only software I downloaded before the language pack were a couple of high priority security updates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the **English** settings by opening the **Region and Language** properties box and doing the following.

**Administrative** tab and then **Copy settings**

[image]

Check out all the settings to make sure they are in **English** and then check both boxes in the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is down to the system still being Hungarian.

The way to change this is to go to `Control Panel` > `Region and Language`, then click the `Administrative` tab followed by the `Copy Settings` button.

From here, you can change the other language settings such as the login screen and UAC prompts (which officially run as system - not as your user).

[image]